# Why in jenkins extensions points, does the ConsoleLogFilter uses OutputStream and not String?

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins

I want to create a plugin that hides certain string before they are written to the Console log. From what I've read, the ConsoleLogFilter is perfect extension point for that.

From the description of the ConsoleLogFilter it says the following: 'A hook to allow filtering of information that is written to the console log'

But, the only method available to override is 'decorateLogger' which an input variable of OutputStream, meaning, I can't read the stream and filter things I want based on the stream.

Am I missing something?

Tzach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you override the `decorateLogger` method and return an OutputStream that does the filtering. This is called [The Decorator Pattern](http://drpaulcarter.blogspot.de/2009/05/decorator-pattern.html). The JDK provides a [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) class that can be used to implement such filters.

Have a look at the [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin), which implements a filter for passwords: [MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mask-passwords-plugin/blob/mask-passwords-2.8/src/main/java/com/michelin/cio/hudson/plugins/maskpasswords/MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper.java#L134-L140)

Comment: It seems like the LineTransformationOutputStream class is the answer. Thanks! :)